# How to obtain point data from a fitting curve?

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I plotted curves by fitting some existing points using gnuplot.

code as followings:

```
f1(x)=a1/(x**b1)+c1
fit f1(x) "41a091_input.txt" u 1:2 via a1,b1,c1
plot f1(x) with line lt 1 lw 4 lc rgb "blue" notitle, \
    '41a091_input.txt' using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars lw 2.2 lc rgb "blue" title "∑41a(091)"
```

Data as followings:

```
21.8124 1.11693 0.00545168
30.8669 1.07328 0.00485237 
44.6701 1.04708 0.00411839
53.6699 1.03787 0.00301346
75.9751 1.02555 0.00304312
```

My question is:

How to get data from any point on this curve?
Like when x=50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you have your fitting function `f1(x)` and the parameters `a1,b1,c1` have been fitted. So, in order to get the value at `x=50`, simply type `print f1(50)`.
Or if you want to plot it:

```
### start code
reset session

$Data <<EOD
21.8124 1.11693 0.00545168
30.8669 1.07328 0.00485237 
44.6701 1.04708 0.00411839
53.6699 1.03787 0.00301346
75.9751 1.02555 0.00304312
EOD

f1(x)=a1/(x**b1)+c1
fit f1(x) $Data u 1:2 via a1,b1,c1
print sprintf("a1: %g, b1: %g, c1: %g", a1,b1,c1)

XValue = 50
set label 1 at XValue,f1(XValue)+0.01 sprintf("f1(%g): %g",XValue,f1(XValue)) 
set arrow 1 from XValue,graph 0 to XValue,graph 1 nohead ls 0

plot f1(x) with line lt 1 lw 4 lc rgb "blue" notitle,\
 $Data using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars lw 2.2 lc rgb "blue" title "∑41a(091)",\
 [XValue:XValue] f1(XValue) w p lt 6 lc rgb "red" ps 2
### end of code
```

which results in something like:
[image]

Comment: OMG you saved my life! That works! However i still do not understand some details, like what does [XValue:XValue] using for?

Comment: And what if i want to add a vertical dashed line through this point?

Comment: just remove the `[XValue:XValue]` and see what will happen. This limits the range to one datapoint. Vertical dashed line: for example with `set arrow 1 from XValue, graph 0 to XValue, graph 1 nohead ls 0` Maybe there are better ways to achieve both things.

Comment: Probably a better way to plot a single point `plot '+' using (XValue):(f1(XValue)) w p lt 6 lc rgb "red" ps 2`